# Git merge tool that also shows the remote base

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I used to work with 3-way merge tools like BC3, SourceGear, or P4 which usually show 4 components: **base**, **left**, **right**, and **merged result**.

What *Git* seems to do, and rightly so especially in cases of a `git rebase --onto` seem to be a "4-way merge": **left-base**, **left**, **right-base**, **right**, **merged result**. Or in other words, taking the diff patch done on the left (local) side, and trying to merge it with a diff patch done on the right (remote) side.

Merged = Left-Diff-Path + Right-Diff-Path

Would you know any good tool that shows those 4 components if there is any such support nowadays?

Comment: So, I reworded the  title to make it clearer the question is how to to view the remote base. Many folks would consider "4-way merge" to be BASE, LOCAL, REMOTE, MERGED, which is not what this question is actually asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think one exists. I've always heard that BC3 and P4Merge were the best ones.

Comment: Can you offer any clarification on how P4Merge for example might be used to merge 4 file versions as described in the question, if that's possible? I find myself wanting to merge the changes in one branch into another branch that has undergone its own changes since it branched from the first. I know Team Foundation Server can do this automatically (for the most party) if you check in code, but I want to do this before I check anything in sometimes.

Comment: That's not what was asked. If you want 4 variations merged, you can with octopus merge `git merge branch1 branch2 branch3 branch4`. If you get conflicts, octopus merge will abort, you can't resolve more than 2 versions conflicting. That said, you can merge each of them 1 at a time. then squash all merges into the first. You preserve what would be the parents had the octopus merge worked by writing all the SHA1s of the tips of the branches you're merging on separate lines into `.git/MERGE_HEAD`. Now when you commit, the commit you generate will have the 4 parents you want.

Comment: After further research I learned that my understanding of 3-way merge must have been confused, and all I really needed was a simple 3-way merge in my case. Sorry for the confusion. I thought when I had two branches, a common root version, and a modified version of one branch that I wanted to merge into the other I needed more than a 3-way merge, but I didn't. I can simply ignore the common root version apparently and things work great in my case.

Comment: VIMDIFF does 4 way these days.

Answer (score 2):

[diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) seems to be installed by default on my Fedora17 workstation; it also happens to be the default in some way as I didn't specify anything on my .gitconfig, still:

```
git mergetool
```

just opens it, right away showing the correct files for editing.

Meld seems able to deal with it as well, I had to install it and is looking better.

Comment: Not sure why my answer gets voted down. Diffuse does properly show 4 way merges. Adding Meld as well.

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot showing a 4-way diff/merge? I've only seen diffuse/meld do two-way.

Comment: Ok, it looks like `diffuse` *will* do an arbitrary way diff, but only on single files.

Comment: Neither diffuse nor meld support a way of seeing the "right-base" the question asked for. This is because git doesn't provide it to them. I added an answer providing more context.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think git doesn't provide the info you want to mergetools. It only has the following variables available when defining the command and arguments to call the mergetool with (from [Git - git-mergetool Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool)). So it essentially doesn't have a "right-base".

- BASE is the name of a temporary file containing the common base of the files to be merged, if available
- LOCAL is the name of a temporary file containing the contents of the file on the current branch
- REMOTE is the name of a temporary file containing the contents of the file from the branch being merged
- MERGED contains the name of the file to which the merge tool should write the results of a successful merge

In theory someone could write a tool that queries git to find out the merge state rather than being called by git as a mergetool. In that case it could get the info you are suggesting. But I am not personally aware of tools that do that (the commands `meld` and `diffuse` suggested in other answer do not).

I agree what you are asking for would be useful. Really what I personally would like to see is BASE, LOCAL, REMOTE, and "REMOTE-DIFF" - the latter being what patch would show for remote commit which is usually what I someone wants to apply.